# Java Stream converting char to ascii

Tags: java, stream

so I all I want for this to do is to print out the chars instead of the ascii values...

```
     str.chars()
        .distinct()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

this is the output:

```
     97
     98
     99
     100
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can map the characters accordingly using the mapToObj method

```
str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by casting the `int` to `char` as below

```
str.chars()
        .distinct()
        .forEach(x -> System.out.println((char)x));
```

Comment: thank you! Could I use forEach to convert back to char and save in an array?

Comment: Yes definitely you can do it. Rather than printing it add it to char[]. like char[] cArray = new char[]. And then cArray[index] = (char)x